# Classifying equilibrium point (0,0) with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=0,-1$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-system

I am given a nonlinear dynamical system:

$\dot x = x^2y-x$

$\dot y = 4xy^2+4y^2-x^2y-xy$

I was able to find all the equilibrium points and classify them, expect $e_0=(0,0)$. I found that the Jacobian evaluated at $e_0$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Which gives eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=0,-1$. I have seen that if $\lambda_2>0$ then the classification is trivial, however this is not the case. The only way to do it (apparently) is to use the Central Manifold Theorem and the Hartman-Grobman Theorem, however I have difficult time applying it (I have never studied it). So my question is:

$1.$ Is the application of the Central Manifold and Hartman-Grobman theorems necessary ? Are there any other way to do classify $e_0$ ?